# LAN network access missing

Tags: networking, drivers, network-manager

I have installed Windows 11 and Ubuntu 22.04. Both systems work(ed) properly.
In Ubuntu I had problems due to a missing Nvidia driver and solved this issue by setting the indicator `install proprietary drivers`. Now the LAN network access is missing. How can this be resolved without having network access? It was working properly before.

In `Settings -> Network` only the VPN entry is displayed.

When I boot via the USB stick I used to install Ubuntu in `Settings -> Network` the Wired connection is available as `Connected - 1000 Mb/s`

Windows 11 has proper network access. So the issue is not related to my network or computer.

`/etc/netplan/01-network-manager-all.yaml` looks like this

```
network:
    version: 2
    renderer: NetworkManager
```

`sudo netplan generate` leads to `WARNING: Permissions for /etc/netplan/01-network-manager-all.yaml are too open. Netplan configuration should not be accessible by others`.
Same for `sudo netplan apply`.

I'm using a Gigabyte mainboard.